# Do I need to worry about concurrency using WebAssembly in Node?

Tags: webassembly

I have some code written in AssemblyScript that I've compiled to WASM. I plan on invoking the WASM in both an Express app and Cloudflare workers.

I understand Node's execution model and how you generally don't need to worry about concurrency. I'm not sure if this holds true when invoking the WebAssembly runtime.